# difference between function with @objc in front and function doesn't have @objc

Tags: swift, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter, observers

In one of the view controller files in my project, there are two functions, one is called in viewdidload and another is called by Notification and observers. Those functions do exactly the same thing, and I was wondering if I get rid of one of the functions, especially the one without using @objc in front. (otherwise I get an error)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureNotifications()
    displayItems()
}

func displayItems() {
    fetchLiveEvents { [weak self] in
        self?.applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}

func configureNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateExistingItem), name: .updateExistingItem, object: nil)
}

@objc func updateExistingItem() {
    fetchLiveEvents { [weak self] in
        self.applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}
```

Since I'm using the notification canter, I cannot get rid of @objc in front of updateExistingItem function. However, the updateExistingItem and displayItems are doing exactly something, so I feel it's kinda redundant and I was thinking to get rid of displayItems function from the viewDidLoad and call updateExistingItem (probably change the name) in viewdidLoad instead.

Is there any convention in Swift programming that keeps both @objc and normal function when they are doing the same thing? or is it just a personal preference and doesn't matter to leave both of them?

Comment: The one with `@objc` is used when you call a function with `#selector`.

Comment: yeah, so I must use the `@objc func updateExistingItem` to call the function with `#selector`. And instead of calling `displayItems` in the `viewdidload`, when I write `updateExistingItem()` in `viewdidload`, it also works. So I was wondering if calling a function with `@objc` without using a selector is ok or not. If it's not the ideal way to call, I'd use  `func displayItems` and `@objc func updateExistingItem` in the file.

Comment: There is no issue to add `@objc` (when it's possible) before a function. It's just to tell that using the bridge, an Objective-C code can call it. Being "pure Objective-C code", or under the hood code with `#selector` (which is a "legacy" stuff, since Swift is based on previously Objective-C APIs and some mechanisms).

Comment: @Larme
I get that!!
So, I'll keep the one with `@objc` in my project. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

viewDidLoad just call once  when the screen is present if you go to another screen by pushing a viewcontroller or presenting a controller and comeback to this controller the viewDidLoad didn't triggered  it will never called again until the next run / terminate the app and open again.

so your function is called by the notification to run again when this screen appear.

```
// just called once 
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNotifications()
        displayItems()
      }
// just called every time when you popped a viewController or tap on tab bar items using tabbar controller


        override func viewWillAppear() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            displayItems()
          }
```

in your scenario may be you came back to this screen by present some other screen and do some functionality there and call the notification to be trigger on this screen so nothing will trigger if your present a screen by modal presentation style over full screen
That's why called the notification to start displaying item again

```
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNotifications()
        displayItems()
    }
    

// called once 
    func displayItems() {
        fetchLiveEvents { [weak self] in
            self?.applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: true)
        }
    }
    

    func configureNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateExistingItem), name: .updateExistingItem, object: nil)
    }
    

// called every time when you trigger notifcation
    @objc func updateExistingItem() {
        fetchLiveEvents { [weak self] in
            self.applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: true)
        }
    }
```